# CefSharp v47 Won't Load Pack Files

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a C# WPF project that is deployed on client machines. Previously, we were using cefsharp v33, successfully, and now we are in the process of upgrading to v47. We have an issue where the `ChromiumWebBrowser` loads and displays content but the formatting is off. This is usually observed when packs aren't loaded.

In debug.log, I get the following errors:

```
[0223/175353:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(305)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0223/175353:ERROR:extension_system.cc(71)] Failed to parse extension manifest.
[0223/175353:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(305)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0223/175354:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(305)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30373
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30380
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30379
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30381
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30370
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30382
[0223/175354:ERROR:content_client.cc(341)] No data resource available for id 30371
```

[`CefSharp.DependencyChecker.AssertAllDependenciesPresent()`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/DependencyChecker.cs) prints the following:

```
Unable to locate required Cef/CefSharp dependencies:
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
Missing:CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
Missing:CefSharp.Core.dll
Missing:CefSharp.dll
Missing:icudtl.dat
Missing:libcef.dll
Executing Assembly Path:C:\myapp
```

The problem is that all files are present in the C:\myapp directory (as specified [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary/blob/master/README.txt)). Therefore, I'm not sure why these files aren't being loaded up.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

More info:

- We're building against x86
- Breaking changes in codebase accounted for
- VC++ 2013 Redist (x86 and x64) installed on client
- msvcp120.dll, msvcr120.dll, vccorlib120.dll included in c:\myapp directory
- Everything loads fine on dev machine (with VS2013)
- Issue observed on multiple client machines

Comment: Are you sure it's a `CefSharp` problem? Sounds more like a permissions problem. Try something like `Process Monitor` to gather more information.